# Adding 'x-total-count' with django corsheaders

Tags: django, react-admin, django-cors-headers

How do i manage to add the 'x-total-count' in my django cors response header?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'languages'

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'x-total-count',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',


]


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]
```

.
.
.

This is how my setting.py looks like

This is what the error looks like:

> Warning: Missing translation for key: "The X-Total-Count header is 
>       missing in the HTTP Response. The jsonServer Data Provider expects 
>       responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the 
>       total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using 
>       CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose- 
>       Headers header"

I wasnt able to solve this problem even tho i looked at many related questions. The django cors-headers docs do not include an guide how to add the 'x-total-count'

Comment: Is your app running behind a proxy/firewall? They tend to filter headers and only allow certain header infos. can you verify django does not deliver the header?

Comment: The frontend and the backend are both running on localhost so there is no proxy/firewall. The response header i get when get request the server looks like:Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 06 Aug 2019 10:37:43 GMT
Location: /languages/?_end=10&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.5
Vary: Origin

Comment: Sorry don't know that package, but check https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/blob/71a938c8ed44f893a0689bd098dc10273418913d/README.rst#cors_expose_headers it seems like you have to set `CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS` too.

Comment: This is what i did. Still the same error..

Comment: Does your API returns a header `X-Total-Count` or does it use `Content-Range`?

Comment: @xlass, did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

In order to make React Admin work with Django REST Framework, we have to set a few custom pagination, headers, etc

For example, here is my implementation of these files:

```py
# pagination.py
from collections import OrderedDict
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination


class ReactAdminPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_query_param = "page"
    page_size_query_param = "perPage"

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        count = self.page.paginator.count
        item_starting_index = self.page.start_index() - 1
        item_ending_index = self.page.end_index() - 1

        content_range = "items {0}-{1}/{2}".format(
            item_starting_index, item_ending_index, count
        )

        headers = {"Content-Range": content_range}

        return Response(
            OrderedDict(
                [
                    ("count", count),
                    ("next", self.get_next_link()),
                    ("previous", self.get_previous_link()),
                    ("results", data),
                ]
            ),
            headers=headers,
        )
```

```py
# filtering.py
import json
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend


def sort_queryset(queryset, value):
    try:
        [field, order] = json.loads(value)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        return queryset

    if field and order:
        return queryset.order_by(f"-{field}" if order == "DESC" else field)

    return queryset


def filter_queryset_for_multiple(queryset, key, value):
    filter_params = {}
    filter_params[key] = value.split(",")
    return queryset.filter(**filter_params)


def filter_queryset_for_nullable(queryset, key, value):
    nullable = True if value == "true" else False if value == "false" else None

    if nullable is None:
        return queryset

    filter_params = {}
    filter_params[key] = nullable
    return queryset.filter(**filter_params)


def filter_queryset_for_reference(queryset, key, value):
    f = True if value == "true" else False if value == "false" else value

    filter_params = {}
    filter_params[key] = f
    return queryset.filter(**filter_params)


class ReactAdminFilterBackend(DjangoFilterBackend):
    def get_filterset_kwargs(self, request, queryset, view):
        for key, value in request.query_params.items():
            if key == "sort" and value:
                queryset = sort_queryset(queryset, value)
            elif key.endswith("__in"):
                queryset = filter_queryset_for_multiple(queryset, key, value)
            elif key.endswith("__isnull"):
                queryset = filter_queryset_for_nullable(queryset, key, value)
            elif "__" in key:
                queryset = filter_queryset_for_reference(queryset, key, value)

        return {"data": request.query_params, "queryset": queryset, "request": request}
```

Comment: does this solution worked ? did anyone tried other than the author. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is https://github.com/bmihelac/ra-data-django-rest-framework
It works like a magic. Hope this is useful.